# How to construct a form (using Angular reactive forms - form builder) with live data coming from the server

Tags: angular

I spend the last 2 days trying different ways to get the data in the right order but I just couldn't, basically I get some data from the server and display it for the client plus some extra fields which the client need to fill out.

**This is my data**

```
formConfiguration = { // it's dynamic !! coming back from the server!
    dateSupply: {
        name: "dateSupply",
        validators: [
            Validators.required,
        ]
    },    
    products: [
        { 
            name: "product_1",
            costPerUnit: 3,
            quantityPerCarton: 10,
            value: 0,
            validators: [
                Validators.required,
            ]
        },
        { 
            name: "product_2",
            costPerUnit: 4,
            quantityPerCarton: 20,
            value: 0,
            validators: [
                Validators.required,
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

**this is what I did**

```
createOrderForm(products) {

    const group = this.formBuilder.group({});

    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

        const control = this.fb.control(products[i].value, products[i].validators || []);
        group.addControl(products[i].name, control);
    };

    return group;

};
```

**this is what I need..**

```
form structure:
       controls:
           dateSupply: FormControl,
           products: FormArray,
               0 : FormGroup
                   controls:
                       name: FormControl
                       costPerUnit: FormControl
                       ...
               1 : FormGroup
                   controls:
                       name: FormControl
                       costPerUnit: FormControl
                       ...
```

please help..

Comment: `products = [ ` change in `products: [`

Comment: I did, thank you..

Comment: Does the solution below work?

Comment: i'm afraid not.. but I will update stackblitz with a cloned object example

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: @Chris, I did not get the data like I asked.. here is a link to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ww48qg) please see if you can help.. thank you !!!

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-giax58

Comment: @Chris.. still not the way I need it. supply date perfect, products array is good down to each form group, problem is that each group has wrong form controls.. check the console on your stackblitz.

Comment: which of these do you need in formGroup 'formControlName, productName, costPerUnit, quantityPerCarton, value'. but I made the structure that you can't change properly?

Comment: I need all of the above inside each group using dynamic keys meaning "costPerUnit" might change tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

You must use FormArray. I made an example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ypr7s)

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
  dateSupply: this._fb.control(formConfiguration.dateSupply.name),
  products: this._fb.array(
    formConfiguration.products.map(({ value, validators }) =>
      this._fb.group({
        name: this._fb.control(value, validators || [])
      }),
    ),
  ),
});
```